What is the difference between the menuitemradio and radio roles in ARIA?
I have just learnt about menuitemradio when I was searching about radio role on MDN.
However, seems there is no explanation about the difference between them..
Can I confirm that they are actually the same, but:

menuitemradio role can only be used inside <menu> or element with role="menu"
radio role should used inside role="radiogroup"

Are these correct?

Additionally, so that:

Can radio role be used in <menu> or role="menu"?


menuitemradio is not for radio buttons... It is for control elements that are not an interactive element by default...

The roles menuitemradio and radio are not the same.
The radio role is the role that HTML's native radio buttons have (<input type="radio">). This is a role for custom radio buttons, which should be grouped in an element with the radiogroup role.
The menuitemradio role is not an alternative to the above; it does not represent a radio button. It is a kind of option in a set of options in a menu, where only one of those options can be selected at any time. An example is the setting for the bookmarks toolbar in Firefox:

Elements with this role can only be used inside element with the following roles: menu, menubar or (if no other role accurate describes the container role) group.
Radio buttons or custom element with the radio role should not be used in menus.
